# Color Gradient in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing

How can I create a color gradient in Blender 2.8?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

[image]

Use the Mapping node to move the orientation.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. Do you know by chance how I can export my object with my newly made color gradient ?

Comment: If you wanna use your object in another application like substance, Unreal, unity or so; you need to have UV´s and bake your textures.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just follow this basic shader setup. you can change how the colors mix together in the color ramp settings. I have it set to constant so that it's just there's no mixing, but there are other options in that tab that will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you that almost worked! The thing is I want to It to be dark on bottom and bright on top. How can I do that? https://www.dropbox.com/s/toqry8jq256hvj7/Bildschirmfoto%202019-07-16%20um%2021.30.13.png?dl=0